# Second degree equation solutions involving and / Or

Tags: polynomials

Lets suppose we have this eq: $x^2-x -2 =0$. It factors into $(x+1)(x-2)=0$, if we solve it as an second equation with Delta equals 9, we have to conclude that the equation accepts two solutions: $x_1 = -1$ and $x_2 = 2$. If we solve it as a factored polynomial, we have to conclude that the equation accepts either $ x = -1$ Or $x =2$ and these are very different conclusions if not contradictory. How should I see this?

Comment: There is no difference.  However you slice it, $x=-1$ and $x=2$ are the two solutions.  If you want to choose a solution, you can choose either $x=-1$ or $x=2$.

Comment: We use ***or*** because, x can't be -1 and 2 at the same time. Also either value of x would make the expression - zero.

Comment: It is the difference between $\{x\in\mathbb{R}:\ x^2-x-2=0\}=\{-1\}\cup\{2\}$. In words this is 'The set of solutions is consists of $-1$ and $2$. On the other hand there is the implication $x^2-x-2=0$ implies $x=-1$ or $x=2$.

Comment: I agree with @RobertIsrael; I’m just wondering:   when you wrote introductory, did you mean contradictory?

Comment: Yeah, I meant contradictory.

Answer (score 1):

Whether you solved your equation with factoring or using the quadratic formula, the equation has two solutions.

The solutions are, as you have mentioned, $x=-1$ and $x=2.$

Of course these solutions are different and there is room for confusion when we  use the same notation $x$ for two different values.

In order to avoid confusion, we may use $x_1=-1$ and $x_2=2.$

Comment: That s what I did!

Comment: Yes, that solves the problem of  "and" or "or".

Answer (score 1):

As everyone here is saying, but in other words maybe,

The statement "the solutions of the equation are $-1$ **and** $2$" is correct,

And the statement "$(x-2)(x+1)=0 \implies x=2$ **or** $x=-1$"is also correct. (Note that the last statement mentioned is same as saying "$x^2-x-2=0 \implies x=2$ **or** $x=-1$").

So the form of the equation doesn't actually matter, it just about using the words in a proper manner.

I guess (not sure if I am right) that what dazzeled you is the idea that some teachers tell students to use the word "**or**" when there is the equal sign $=$ and the word "**and**" when there is the sign $\ne$.

If so, usually teachers mean by that that if you have a fraction having $(x-2)(x+1)$ as its **denominator** then when asked for the domain of definition of this fraction you must say that we want $x \ne 2$ **and** $x \ne -1$ because both numbers give me a zero in my denominator and that is unaccepted.(i.e. we want $x$ to be different from both numbers at the same time).

So in the second statement above we **can't** have $x=2$ **and** $x=-1$ at the same time (because $x$ takes one value at a time) but here $x$ **can** be different than $2$ and $-1$ at the same time and that is what we want here.